# how to write to file when using gulp and mocha?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

I have a sample gulp task that uses Mocha json reporter. I would like to write that json output to a file. Would appreciate some inputs.

Here is my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var util = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('myreport', function() {
    return gulp.src(['tests.js'], { read: false })
        .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'json' }))  //how do I write this to a file?
        .on('error', util.log);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made it work looking at the source code. It seems that [gulp-mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/json-stream.js#L41) does not follow the gulp pipeline to push it's outsource. You may use `process.stdout.write` though temporary mapping the outcome during the execution of the task.

Here is a simple example.

```
  var gulp = require('gulp'),
  mocha = require('gulp-mocha'),
  gutil = require('gulp-util'),
  fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('test', function () {
  //pipe process.stdout.write during the process
  fs.writeFileSync('./test.json', '');
  process.stdout.write = function( chunk ){
    fs.appendFile( './test.json', chunk );
  };

  return gulp.src(['hello/a.js'], { read: false })
      .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'json' }))
      .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

Comment: This also writes console.log prints to the JSON file, which render useless..
Do you have a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @GalMargalit Unfortunately no, this is a simple workaround to map the output into a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use mochawesome reporter, you'll get JSON output and much more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome

Another advantage of using this reporter is that you won't break your JSON writing stream on console.log messages etc.

```
.pipe(mocha({reporter: 'mochawesome'}))
```

[image: mochawesome screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just pipe it to `gulp.dest`?

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./somewhere'));
```